# Single SQS batch processing via lambda no matter how many messages are available

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm wondering if anyone has solved for this type of functionality with Lambda specifically. In the past we have done this fairly elegantly via eks-based queue processors, where depending on a config value the queue is either on or off *OR* it knows to pull only a single batch and turn the queue back off.

With lambda however the trigger is simply enabled/disabled. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to allow only a single batch through. We use this as a final check for testing purposes, so as not to open the floodgates, but instead monitor the results of that single batch before turning the queue back on.

Comment: With the SQS -> Lambda integration, SQS handles polling and each event is delivered to Lambda.  A reasonable alternative for you might be to set lambda concurrency to 1.  Alternatively, there's no hard and fast rule that the lambda *must* get *all* of its events from the SQS -> lambda integration.  You certainliy write the lambda to be able to pull messages itself based on input config and invoke the lambda yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to process only a single batch concurrently, before moving onto the next batch.

I can think of two ways to accomplish this:

1. Using an event-source mapping to trigger the Lambda, with
   a `ParallelizationFactor` of 1
2. Polling the queue yourself, via SQS `ReceiveMessage`

If you need to halt processing for an indeterminate amount of time, rather than simply guaranteeing serial non-concurrent processing of batches, your best solution will be consuming the queue yourself. As you pointed out, disabling the trigger is not an elegant solution.

You can build your own locking logic within the queue consumer, and you can easily trigger the consumer on a regular interval using a CloudWatch Event Rule. You may even find it helpful to trigger the consumer from an event-source mapping (for example to avoid waiting the poll interval), but I suggest you still poll the queue regularly to account for ignored messages (eg when the consumer is 'locked').